# Logging SQL script errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-scripts

I have a SQL script for postgres file with following command.

```
COPY product_master(productId, productName) FROM 'product.txt' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

I want to handle errors of this command (log the error)

example

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates.

Does the `COPY` command return any value ? If no, then how to log the output of the shell script?

Answer (score 2):

You can log any and all messages (error, warning, ..) with a plethora of additional information in the **database log file**. This is standard behavior. Of course your database cluster has to be configured to do so. [Read the fine manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html).

Dpending on your client you should also be able to get **error messages** as direct answer from the database server. Note that errors are reported on a different stream than data output. Like `stout` and `stderr` in the shell.

From the **shell** you would probably call [`psql -f`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) to execute a script. See what happens in this demo:

Create a dummy SQL script in the shell:

```
vim test.sql
```

Put something like this into it:

```
CREATE temp table x (a int primary key, b int);
insert into x values (1,2),(3,4);
COPY x TO '/var/lib/postgres/dev/test.out';
COPY x FROM '/var/lib/postgres/dev/test.out';
```

Execute it:

```
psql mydb -f test.sql
```

Output depends on various [settings like `client_min_messages`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html):

```
psql:test.sql:2: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "x_pkey" for table "x"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
psql:test.sql:4: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "x_pkey"
KONTEXT:  COPY x, line 1: "1    2"
```

Since I have configured `log_statement = all` (among others) my server log reads:

```
2011-11-15 22:36:23 CET postgres LOG:  statement: CREATE temp table x (a int primary key, b int);
2011-11-15 22:36:23 CET postgres LOG:  statement: insert into x values (1,2),(3,4);
2011-11-15 22:36:23 CET postgres LOG:  statement: COPY x FROM '/var/lib/postgres/dev/test.out';
2011-11-15 22:36:23 CET postgres ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "x_pkey"
2011-11-15 22:36:23 CET postgres CONTEXT:  COPY x, line 1: "1  2"
2011-11-15 22:36:23 CET postgres STATEMENT:  COPY x FROM '/var/lib/postgres/dev/test.out';
```

I would not use `log_statement = all` on a productive server. That produces **huge** log files.